# How do I quote this? I only want to use the first and last parts

Tags: quotations

But ***Dawes, dispatched by patriot leader Dr. Joseph Warren, only carried general news warning*** Hancock and Adams that the British were likely to make some military move to capture them. ***Dawes didn't know any of the specifics of the British movements.***

Answer (score 1):

Original:

But Dawes, dispatched by patriot leader Dr. Joseph Warren, only carried general news warning Hancock and Adams that the British were likely to make some military move to capture them. Dawes didn't know any of the specifics of the British movements.

Quoted:

**"Dawes, dispatched by patriot leader Dr. Joseph Warren, only carried general news warning . . . Dawes didn't know any of the specifics of the British movements."**

Just use three ellipses with a space before and a space after them along with a space in-between each period. If you begin the quote into part of the passage, it is ok to start the quotation mark there.

Sources:

[Omitting Words From Direct Quotation](http://writingcommons.org/open-text/research-methods-methodologies/integrate-evidence/incorporate-evidence/613-omitting-words-from-a-direct-quotation-mla)

[Punctuation Guide: Ellipses](http://www.thepunctuationguide.com/ellipses.html)